# In ZooKeeper, Could I use async getData() on a non-exist znode?

Tags: java, apache-zookeeper

Even I called exists() method, I should check Code.NoNode too.

Thus could I use getData() method directly?

I notice the sync getData() will throw exception if node does not exist. Thus will I got any penalty on performance or other aspect if I called an async getData on a non-exist znode?

Thank you!

Comment: I do notice that when a nonode exception gets thrown, the server logs it.  That act of logging has a bit of overhead, but how much, I do not know.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to get the content of the znode you should use getData instead of using exists and then getData.

Because anyway you should check for Code.NoNode after getting response from getData. So why don't call it directly?

Comment: This is just what I think. And my question is whether the ``NoNode'' exception will cause any impaction on performance?

Comment: But you checking for this exception anyway